# Jenkins: How to use environment variable injected in build in promotion step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a managed script in my build. The scrip provides an env var:

```
/bin/sh
TEST="hellooo"

echo "WORD=$TEST" > build.properties
```

This script is executed in my build. After that I inject env vars in my build using `$WORKSPACE/build.properties`. In the next step I'm able to echo $WORD and I get "hellooo".

But my build promotion which is using this variable is not picking up the value. How can I make this work?